# From how much hashpower one may consider starting a public mining pool?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, mining-pool-setup, mining-profitability

I have a small mining farm, mining in a public pool. I plan to increase the hashpower of the farm in the coming months. 
I also consider starting a public mining pool and move my hashpower to the new pool. 
From how much hashpower it can be worthy to start a public mining pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no definite number here... It mostly depends on how lucky you feel ;)

If you think that you will be the only miner connected to your pool once you make it public, that will be the equivalent of solo mining then... Depends on your hash rate (and lots of luck), this might or might not be profitable for you. However, every beginning is hard, so once you make your pool public, be sure to announce it around and attract miners as soon as possible and just be patient and hope that other will connect too...